# When would you use pivot_root over switch_root?

Tags: linux, startup, init, initramfs

I'm wanting to understand the Linux init process better in order to netboot a system over ceph rather than nfs.

In the process I've come across two forms of switching root.  One called switch_root, and the other called pivot_root.  These scripts being run from an in memory filesystem (initramfs) obtained via tftp using the pxe boot process.

When would you use one over the other?  I've seen both used in some init script's placed in root.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a wonderful explanation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160730094856/http://wiki.sourcemage.org/HowTo(2f)Initramfs.html). However, let me try to put in a shorter format of what I understood in the answer.

**Shorter Version**

1. While the system boots, it needs an early userspace. It can be
   achieved using either initramfs or initrd.
2. **initrd** is loaded into ramdisk which **is an actual** **FILE SYSTEM**.
3. **initramfs** is **not** a **file system**.
4. For *initrd* `pivot_root` is used and for *initramfs* `switch_root` is used.

**Longer Version**

Now, to the detailed explanation of what I had put above.

> While both an initramfs and an initrd serve the same purpose, there
>   are 2 differences. The most obvious difference is that an initrd is
>   loaded into a ramdisk. It consists of an actual filesystem (typically
>   ext2) which is mounted in a ramdisk. An initramfs, on the other hand,
>   is not a filesystem. It is simply a (compressed) cpio archive (of type
>   newc) which is unpacked into a tmpfs. This has a side-effect of making
>   the initramfs a bit more optimized and capable of loading a little
>   earlier in the kernel boot process than an initrd. Also, the size of
>   the initramfs in memory is smaller, since the kernel can adapt the
>   size of the tmpfs to what is actually loaded, rather than relying on
>   predefined ramdisk sizes, and it can also clean up the ram that was
>   used whereas ramdisks tend to remain in use (due to details of the
>   pivot_root implementation).
>
> There is also another side-effect difference: how the root device (and
>   switching to it) is handled. Since an initrd is an actual filesystem
>   unpacked into ram, the root device must actually be the ramdisk. For
>   an initramfs, there is a kernel "rootfs" which becomes the tmpfs that
>   the initramfs is unpacked into (if the kernel loads an initramfs; if
>   not, then the rootfs is simply the filesystem specified via the root=
>   kernel boot parameter), but this interim rootfs should not be
>   specified as the root= boot parameter (and there wouldn't be a way to
>   do so, since there's no device attached to it). This means that you
>   can still pass your real root device to the kernel when using an
>   initramfs. With an initrd, you have to process what the real root
>   device is yourself. Also, since the "real" root device with an initrd
>   is the ramdisk, the kernel has to really swith root devices from one
>   real device (the ramdisk) to the other (your real root). In the case
>   of an initramfs, the initramfs space (the tmpfs) is not a real device,
>   so the kernel doesn't switch real devices. Thus, while the command
>   pivot_root is used with an initrd, a different command has to be used
>   for an initramfs. Busybox provides switch_root to accomplish this,
>   while klibc offers new_root.

Comment: I used `pivot_root` in the past for initramfs, `switch_root` didn't exist at that time. `switch_root` seems to be a convenience method ‎of `pivot_root` which does some more cleanup and also moves `/proc` `/sys` and `/dev` etc and not just the root itself

Comment: You can not use pivot_root on an initramfs rootfs, you will get Invalid Argument. You can only pivot real filesystems.

Comment: @TiCPU Then how would Linux exit early user space?

Comment: The provided solution seems to be wrong. Linus himself says that pivot_root() or chroot() will just change the current processes reference for `/`. So from my understanding it could be any path and has nothing to do with actual "disks".

Comment: @Melab https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455223/pivot-root-from-initramfs-to-new-root-error-invalid-argument

Comment: Wonderful explanation link is dead (to sourcemage wiki).

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot_root` when you want to preserve the original root for some purpose.  `pivot_root` swaps two mount points.

Use `switch_root` when you want to discard the original root.  switch_root is an embellished `chroot` that will move common mount points (/dev, /proc, /sys, etc) into the new root and also attempt to delete everything in the old root.

Conceptually, using `pivot_root` and then doing the mount moves and deletion yourself is functionally equivalent to using `switch_root`.

Also important: `pivot_root` may not be used with an initramfs.